# Service not found in Feathersjs

Tags: node.js, service, feathersjs

I create users service using "feathers generate authentication". But when I tried to create authentication, it seems that it doesn't work. The error is, "NotFound: Service 'users' not found"

Does anyone what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create the `users` service with `feathers generate service` before you generate authentication.

After that, you will be able to use the `users` service for authentication.